# How to distribute application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've never actually wanted to share anything I've made before, but I have a program that I want to be able to pass around to a few people.

How exactly does this work? Is it possible to create just an exe file?

I am using 2 third party libraries with my project. How will this affect things?

Comment: You will need to create a Deployment project. goto File Add New Project Select Setup and Deployment. You can either select InstallShield or Visual Studio Installer if Visual Studio Installer select the Setup Wizard

Comment: What type of application is it?

Comment: Is there any way to distribute without doing an install? The project isn't very complex, is there no way to create an exe that will run without an install?

Comment: The problem is that you will probably need to register your third party libraries. You can try taking the contents of your bin\debug or bin\release folder and see it will run. the other computers will need to have .Net istalled

Comment: Everything that is needed to run the program (and a couple extra files usually) should be located in your `\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\<project name here>\bin\Release` folder (or \bin\Debug). For the most part, you can just grab the required files from that folder, shove them in a .zip, and distribute them.

_rats, @MarkHall beat me to it :p_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to give content of Release directory, but you must remember to set reference attribute Copy Local to true for external libraries. If you forget give client all libraries you will get runtime error. Better option is use e.g. [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In the future when you update your app it will be the best option.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY) is quick tutorial from lynda.com.